# Cannot send password reset mail by getting user email with const email= event.target.email.value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to send the below password reset mail by getting user email,
const email = event.target.email.value, I have tried but due to the async function, I cannot pass the event parameter? FYI - I am using react hook to send password reset mail. Below code screenshot for your reference.

Finally, I have used here useRef to send reset mail. How can I pass event as a parameter into the async function to send password reset mail?

My code:

const [sendPasswordResetEmail, sending] = useSendPasswordResetEmail(auth);

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const email = event.target.email.value;
    const password = event.target.password.value;
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
}

if (loading || sending) {
    return <Loading></Loading>
}

let from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/";
let loginError;

const navigateRegister = () => {
    navigate('/register')
}

const resetPassword = async () => {
    const email = emailRef.current.value;
    await sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
    if (email) {
        toast('Sent email');
    } else {
        toast('please enter your email address!!')
    }
}
```

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0FuM.png)

Comment: put email and password in state, onSubmit set email and password, use useEffect with dependencies [email, password] to sign in when email and password are defined

Comment: I recommend you copy the code from the screenshot and put it in your post. Also, include the part where `handleSubmit` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `emailRef.current.value` to get the email, as seen in `resetPassword` in your code.